# Race Condition [JAVA]

Tags: java, multithreading

When logging within the if statements I can successfully get the value of the "startTime" variable. My issue arises as soon as I try and access this variable from outside of the if statement.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
String startTime = "";
String endTime = "";
....
....
....
public void dailyHours(){
//Retrieve clockInId (ObjectID for clockInTime)
ParseQuery<ParseObject> startQuery = ParseQuery.getQuery("clockIn");
startQuery.getInBackground(clockInId, new GetCallback<ParseObject>() {
    public void done(ParseObject clockIn, ParseException e) {
        if (e == null) {
            startTime = clockIn.getString("Time");
            Log.d(TAG, "StartTime: " + startTime);
        } else {
            // something went wrong
        }
    }
});

//Retrieve clockOutId (ObjectID for clockOutTime)
ParseQuery<ParseObject> endQuery = ParseQuery.getQuery("clockOut");
endQuery.getInBackground(clockOutId, new GetCallback<ParseObject>() {
    public void done(ParseObject clockOut, ParseException e) {
        if (e == null) {
            endTime = clockOut.getString("Time");
            Log.d(TAG, "EndTime: " + endTime);
        } else {
            // something went wrong
        }
    }
});
```

For example, when the Log.d() gets moved to outside of the ParseQuery, startTime returns back empty.

```
public void dailyHours(){
//Retrieve clockInId (ObjectID for clockInTime)
ParseQuery<ParseObject> startQuery = ParseQuery.getQuery("clockIn");
startQuery.getInBackground(clockInId, new GetCallback<ParseObject>() {
    public void done(ParseObject clockIn, ParseException e) {
        if (e == null) {
            startTime = clockIn.getString("Time");
        } else {
            // something went wrong
        }
    }
});
Log.d(TAG, "StartTime: " + startTime); //startTime returns an empty string when moved here
```

This is where I need the variable to have its value so I can use it. How can I synchronize my threads to eliminate the race condition in my case? From my understanding `GetCallback<ParseObject>()` runs on another thread and can therefore cause my issue.

Comment: yes, that's why the result is given in a callback rather than as a function return value. That's the whole idea of asynchronous calls.

Comment: Can you point me in the right direction?

Comment: add synchronized keyword to your method declaration.
e.g. public synchronized void dailyHours(){

Comment: @TomDillinger and what do you expect that would achieve exactly?

Comment: @jchav don't try to syncrhonize stuff. just do whatever you have to do once you get the startTime value in the callback method.

Comment: @njzk2 How would I go about that? That is where I am lost at the moment.

Comment: `My issue arises as soon as I try and access this variable from outside of the if statement.`. The solution is simple: don't access the variable outside the if block. Put whatever it is you want to do with that variable inside that if block.

Comment: @njzk2 Hm, maybe I'm approaching this the completely wrong way . What I'm essentially trying to do is retrieve two parse objects (The 2 if blocks) and then compute the difference of the two once I have retrieved the objects . If I were to put my code within the if block of one query how would I access the variable retrieved within the other ?

Comment: `ParseQuery` also has a `get` method that is synchronous. Use an asynctask, and put both in the `doInBackground`. Or, you can also use the method that returns a `Task`, then use `Taks.whenAll` to combine your 2 tasks, then use `onSuccess` on the new task to use the 2 results.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a classic multi-threading issue.  One way out is to get the startTime, and maybe the endTime too, under synchronization.  The easiest thing to do is...

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
  String startTime = "";
  String endTime = "";
  ...
  public synchronized void setStartTime(String startTime) {
    this.startTime = startTime;
  }

  public synchronized String getStartTime() {
    return startTime;
  }
  ...
  public void dailyHours() {
    ...
        setStartTime(clockIn.getString("Time"));
        Log.d(TAG, "StartTime: " + getStartTime());
    ...
  }
}
```

"Easiest" is the operative term, there are other ways to achieve this, not least of which is figuring out how to avoid doing this asynchronously altogether.  Multi-threading this to just process some command arguments seems like overkill to me.  Just sayin'